# VBO (Views Bulk Operations) - Bulk Operations field not showing in field list

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

Trying to use VBO in a view of CiviCRM contributions, but when I try to add the Bulk Operations field, it is not listed in the pop-up field list so can't be added.

The rest of the view works (ie can access contribution data), and VBO works if the view is based on eg Users.

What else is needed?

(Drupal 7)

Answer (score 2):

1. Using VBO with CiviCRM views requires the CiviCRM Entity module, so
   make sure that is enabled.
2. CiviCRM Entity does not expose all CiviCRM entities as Drupal
   entities by default.  Go to
   `admin/structure/civicrm-entity/settings` to enable the right
   entities - in this case, Contributions

(Thanks to @jackrabbithanna on chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/85qwezc5d3fo3jr4hxgafoyn4r)